# Using LINQ to surround all "group" elements with the new element "groups" in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I'm new to LINQ and C# but I have an xml file generated from a database table. Within the XML document is a element called "group", I would like to wrap all group elements with the element called "groups".

An extract of the XML document is:

```
<members>
- <user>
  <fullname>John Smith</fullname> 
  <username>SmithA</username> 
  <email>John.smith@test.com/email> 
  <distinguishedName>xxx</distinguishedName> 
  <group>London</group>
  </user>
- <user>
  <fullname>Sue Jones</fullname> 
  <username>JonesS</username> 
  <email>Sue.Jones@test.com/email> 
  <distinguishedName>xxx</distinguishedName> 
  <group>London</group>
  </user>
</members>
```

The end result I struggling to code in C# ASP.NET is:

```
<members>
- <user>
  <fullname>John Smith</fullname> 
  <username>SmithA</username> 
  <email>John.smith@test.com/email> 
  <distinguishedName>xxx</distinguishedName> 
  <groups>
  <group>London</group>
  <groups>
  </user>
- <user>
  <fullname>Sue Jones</fullname> 
  <username>JonesS</username> 
  <email>Sue.Jones@test.com/email> 
  <distinguishedName>xxx</distinguishedName> 
  <groups>
  <group>London</group>
  <groups>
  </user>
</members>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to:

1. Go through each `user` element
2. Add the new `groups` element
3. Add the existing `group` to the new `groups` element
4. Remove the original `group` element

This approach would be similar to this, provided `xml` is an `XElement`:

```
foreach (var user in xml.Elements("user"))
{
    user.Add(new XElement("groups", user.Element("group")));
    user.Element("group").Remove(); 
}
```

If you're using an `XDocument` you could use `xml.Root.Elements("user")` instead.

---

**EDIT:** in response to your comment, if the XML contained multiple numbered groups you could filter on all elements that start with "group" and do almost the same thing.

```
foreach (var user in xml.Elements("user"))
{
    var groups = user.Elements()
                     .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("group"))
                     .ToArray();

    // rename groups
    foreach (var group in groups)
        group.Name = "group";

    user.Add(new XElement("groups", groups));
    groups.Remove();
}
```

Notice that I used `ToArray()` to prevent the `Remove` call from reevaluating the expression, which would incorrectly remove the newly added `groups` element since it too matches the condition of starting with "group." Another way around this would be to change the `Where` predicate to also check that the name ends with a digit. It's extra work to prevent accidentally selecting any other element that may start with "group" but it's up to you based on your knowledge of the XML structure.

Comment: Note that that will only deal with a single group element for each user. I assumed the OP wanted to handle multiple elements - although admittedly it would have been nice if the example had included this.

Comment: @Jon that was my understanding from the OP. I guess that lack of clarity is what prompted my comment to you a few seconds ago as well.

Comment: What if the original XML document  contain group1, group2, group3, groupx elements in each user element that needed to be surrounded by the group element? do you do multiple loops or loops within loops appending the element to the new groups element?

Comment: Or is there a filter that can be used in the doc.Descendants() to select all elements that begin with the string "group"?

Comment: @Mjakda see my update. You can filter using a `Where` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but finally how would I remove the numerical values 1 and 2 from group1 and group2 element names?

Comment: @Mjakda you can loop through the `groups` variable I used previously and set the `Name` property of each element. I've added a `foreach` loop to do this as part of my previous edit.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* this is what you want - it seems to work for me:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var groupedGroups = doc.Descendants("group")
                   .GroupBy(x => x.Parent);

        foreach (var groupedGroup in groupedGroups)
        {
            // Create the new element (copies each <group>)
            groupedGroup.Key.Add(new XElement("groups", groupedGroup));

            // Remove all the old ones
            foreach (var element in groupedGroup)
            {
                element.Remove();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }
}
```

Apologies for the name - it's kinda hard to come up with names when every concept is "group" :)

Comment: Jon I'm not clear about the need for grouping here (i.e., the usage of `GroupBy`).

Comment: @Ahmad: It's to group all the `<group>` elements which have a single parent together within a single `<groups>` element.